# CPU and Memory Utilization from F5 Device ( ADC Load Balancer ) - Node (Server) wise

Tags: snmp, cpu-usage, memory-usage, f5-big-ip

Can somebody help me out to retrieve the CPU and Memory utilization details for the list of nodes available in the F5 inventory using SNMP ( from F5 )

Comment: Could you please edit your question and clarify what you are trying to achieve? Because as it stands now it looks like you expect your loadbalancer to have a record of the CPU load and memory consumption for each of the backend servers/nodes in a pool?

Comment: You are right, Expecting the loadbalancer to expose snmp for CPU and Memoru consumption for each backend servers/nodes in a pool

Comment: It's been while that somebody trusted me with admin access on an F5, but as far as I recall you should be able to configure an health check (performance monitors) that use for instance SNMP or WMI to check CPU and/or memory on the backend servers, but i don't know if the F5 will report the actual CPU load numbers back to you, or only uses them internally  for dynamically weighted load balancing. https://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/products/big-ip_ltm/manuals/product/ltm-monitors-reference-11-2-0/3.html